# Change IP address in ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Right now I'm running a scraping program on my computer. It's massive in size, and unfortunately because of this, my IP address has been banned from the site I need to scrape.  Is there a way that in Ruby, or even just in a simple manner, I can switch my IP address so that I can be allowed back into this site for scraping, or am I out of luck, and I may have to resort to other solutions. It is a 403 Forbidden Error, and for whatever its worth I'm using nokogiri and my user agent is ruby, thanks.

Comment: Your IP address is not related to Ruby. Rebooting your router/modem usually results in a new IP address. [Tor](https://www.torproject.org) could help, too.

Comment: I understand, but whenever I try to scrape the site I get a 403 error due to my IP address, and I am sure it is due to my IP address.  Is there a more efficient way, I see that tore will work for browser purposes, but I need a more efficient pragmatic way to change my IP then just rebooting my router/modem, preferably in ruby if that is an option.

Comment: Ruby just uses your network interface, you cannot simply change your public IP.

Comment: Oh, well okay, thanks anyway, is there possibly any other way that I can get around this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what is massive in size. The size of your program? That should not matter because it is on your computer.

Comment: I'm going through roughly 60,000 pages on a site if my calculations end up being correct, and I have plans to go through more if possible. This is what is massive about the program, and this is why my IP got banned from the site.  The program itself is not extremely large, but the scale of what I am scraping and accessing is.

Comment: You should be gentle when scraping, set your program to take short naps from time to time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can connect through a proxy, and if you have a list of proxy addresses then you can tell ruby to change proxy every x minutes, this will result in a change of the IP that the website thinks you have. Here's a code to scrape google search results through a proxy, to use a proxy list just extend the code a bit.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.set_proxy '78.186.178.153', 8080
page = agent.get('http://www.google.com/')

google_form = page.form('f')
google_form.q = 'new york city council'

page = agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)

page.links.each do |link|
    if link.href.to_s =~/url.q/
        str=link.href.to_s
        strList=str.split(%r{=|&}) 
        url=strList[1] 
        puts url
    end 
end
```

Comment: Wow, really great, thanks so much, I was starting to think I was screwed, this is perfect.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for good proxy servers to use this method with? I have no experience with proxy services.